# doc-view-mode-hook?

Tags: hooks, docview

Whenever I open a pdf in emacs, I'd like to increase the font size. I thought I would just place (doc-view-enlarge) in a 'doc-view-mode-hook. However, I can't find such a hook.

Yet this source claims the hook exists:

http://www.r-bloggers.com/using-doc-view-with-auto-revert-to-view-latex-pdf-output-in-emacs/

What is the hook I am looking for in this case?

Comment: Unfortunately, that source is 5+ years old, and it looks like that hook no longer exists.

Comment: @Dan I see that hook reference in `lisp/doc-view.el` in emacs 24.4 source.

Comment: @kaushalmodi: weird: the only hook I have is `doc-view-clone-buffer-hook`, although I'm on 24.3.

Comment: @Dan That's strange.. I have been using that hook forever now for a different purpose though. `(add-hook 'doc-view-mode-hook 'auto-revert-mode)`

Comment: @user84207 What happens when you use the hook? Does emacs give an error?

Comment: the variable does not exist

Comment: @user84207 What emacs version are you on? Did you try without loading your init file, `\emacs -Q&`? I am on emacs 24.4 stable and after launching `\emacs -Q&` I can successfully evaluate (`C-x C-e`) `(add-hook 'doc-view-mode-hook 'auto-revert-mode)` in the \*scratch\* buffer.

Comment: I believe the confusion is because `doc-view.el` is missing `(defvar doc-view-mode-hook nil)`.

Comment: @kaushalmodi GNU Emacs 24.3.1. I have no problems with my init-file. You can successfully evaluate (add-hook 'any-random-unbound-symbol 'non-existent-command), but normally the hook is `defvar`-ed by the mode that uses it

Comment: @user84207 I think that the `defvar` is not mandatory. I can check the value of the `doc-view-mode-hook` by doing `C-h v` after doing `add-hook` and it also works as intended.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mode hooks exist, whether or not they are predefined variables.

If `doc-view-mode` is a major mode then `doc-view-mode-hook` is alive and well.

That is to say that the coding conventions call for a major mode to run its mode hook when the mode is turned on. But typically ***no hook variable is predefined***.

The doc for `define-derived-mode` tells you that the newly defined mode will run a hook that is constructed by `derived-mode-hook-name`, which interns the hook name.

In other words, no such variable is defined ahead of time, but when you enter the mode its symbol is interned and bound to a local variable, which is run as a hook (the functions in its value are invoked).

If there happens to be a global variable of the same name then that variable is bound (dynamically). But there need not be such a global variable.

From Elisp, [`Major Mode Conventions`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Major-Mode-Conventions.html):

```
 Each major mode should have a normal "mode hook" named
 `MODENAME-mode-hook'.  The very last thing the major mode command
 should do is to call `run-mode-hooks'.  This runs the normal hook
 `change-major-mode-after-body-hook', the mode hook, and then the
 normal hook `after-change-major-mode-hook'.
```

Comment: Awesome. I did not know this. I thought I was at the mercy of the mode's writer's choice to define a hook, including his choice of a naming convention.

Comment: After reading the doc a bit, if you think it could be improved to make this clearer, consider filing an enhancement request: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Actually, yeah, that is what I forgot to add. That I'm pretty sure I had read that part of the docs before, but my impression was still what I expressed above.